# Profit dependent on the previous job time - Job Scheduling problem

Tags: algorithm, job-scheduling, greedy

There are n jobs that need to be processed on a single machine. Job j requires t<sub>j</sub> time units to execute and has a profit value of p<sub>j</sub>. All the jobs are to schedule in time W = summation of t<sub>j</sub>time units.
Scheduling job j to start at time s<sub>j</sub> earns a profit (W - s<sub>j</sub>)*p<sub>j</sub>.

I have already tried a greedy approach for p<sub>j</sub> and s<sub>j</sub> individually as well pj*tj but have been able to come up with a counterexample. I think it can be solved by a greedy algorithm using p<sub>j</sub>/t<sub>j</sub> in decreasing order but not able to prove it. I am just looking for some hints on how to prove it formally.

Answer (score 0):

An approach I have seen before is to consider swapping two adjacent jobs in a proposed schedule. Suppose we have 1,2, where other stuff will take time K and then we hit a deadline. This is better left unswapped if

p1(K + t2) + p2K > p2(K + t1) + p1K

which simplifies to

p1t2 > p2t1

which simplifies to

p1 / t1 > p2 / t2

So if we sort in the way you guessed no swap of adjacent jobs will increase profits, but if there a schedule which does not follow this rule you can improve it by swapping adjacent jobs. So I think your guess is correct.